# PHP: Reading specific csv lines into a two-dimensional array

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, fgetcsv

I have a file arranged like so: 
"url1","info1" 
"url2","info2" 
"url3","info3" ... all the way up to "url15","info15"

I would like to read the last 10 lines of the file into an array such that $pagelist[0][0] would give url5 and $pagelist[0][1] would give info5.

My current code is as follows:

```
$file=fopen(csvfile.txt,"r");
$pagelist=array();
$i=0;
$key=0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    if ($i >= (count($file)-11)) {
        $pagelist[$key]=fgetcsv($file);
        $key++; }
    $i++;
}
fclose($file)
```

When I used print_r($pagelist) it seemed to have loaded all the lines of the file into the array instead of just the last 10. Can anyone see what I've done wrong in my code? thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with you code is that `count($file)` is not doing what you think. `$file` is just a file handle resource, not an array. You end up comparing `$i >= -11`, which will of course always evaluate to `true`/

You might try something like this if you want to just use linux to grab the last ten lines (not sure if you are on linux):

```
$initial_csv = 'csvfile.txt';
$truncated_csv ='csvfile_trun';
$number_of_lines_from_end = 10;
shell_exec('tail -n ' . $number_of_lines_from_end . ' ' . $initial_csv . ' > ' . $truncated_csv);
$file=fopen($truncated_csv,"r");
$pagelist=array();
$i=0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $pagelist[$i]=fgetcsv($file);
    $i++;
}
fclose($file)
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind having the entire file in memory (i.e. the file will remain small), you can read the entire file into an array like this.

```
$csv = 'csvfile.txt';
$number_of_lines_from_end = 10;
$file_array = file($csv);
$line_count = count($file_array);
$start = $line_count - $number_of_lines_from_end - 1;
$pagelist=array();
for ($i = $start; $i < $line_count; $i++) {
    $pagelist[]=fgetcsv($file);
}
```

Comment: If going the `file()` route (huge memory indeed), an `foreach(array_slice($file_array,$line_count-11,10) as $line) $pagelist[]=str_getcsv($line);` seems more apt.

Comment: @Wrikken The only reason I provided the `file()` solution is that it seems the OP is dealing with relatively little data.  If you were talking about thousands of line of data, I would use something like the linux `tail` command to solution to just get the portion of the data is cared about right up front.  You are right that `array_slice()` would work fine just as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `array_slice` doesn't address the memory issue; the use of `file()` means that the file is already read into memory.  `array_slice` just avoids looping through the first n-10 lines.

Comment: @ernie You are correct about the memory consumption. The code shown does not loop through the first n-10 lines, however.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't advocate `file()` for a couple of MBs of logfiles for instance, I was just saying that _if_ we have it, we might as well use it (and your code misses a seeking to the proper line in that part b.t.w.). If I was the OP, I'd go for the `tail` solution most definitely (with proper `escapeshellarg` for dynamic arguments).

Comment: @MikeBrant ah, I hadn't actually read your code; just the OPs and the  `array_slice` comment, and assumed that you had iterated through in a similar manner to the OP.  I just read your code and see you calculate the index and hop to last lines.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Well, I'd hardly call `$i = $start` (neither of which are magic) _'hopping to last lines'_, but that's just nitpicking, it's not a solution meant for big files.

Comment: @Wrikken @MikeBrant I've tried both your solutions and they both work great! Since you think it'll be fastest I'll go with the `tail` one :)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another implementation, for the fun of it (Mike's `tail` is probably fastest):

```
$storage  = new SPLFixedArray(10);
$i = 0;
while(($line = fgets($file)) && ++$i) {
    $storage[$i%10] = $line;
}
$storage = $storage->toArray();
//switch if order is important;
$prepend = array_splice($storage,($i%10)+1,10 - ($i%10));
array_splice($storage,0,0,$prepend);
//interpret csv
$result = array_map('str_getcsv',$storage);
```

Comment: FWIW, a simple 1M lines seems to take about 2 seconds here. Fast enough for shell scripts / crons, waaaaaay to long for HTTP requests.

Answer (score -1):

```
$file=fopen(csvfile.txt,"r");    
$pagelist= [];                  
$temp = fgetcsv($file);          
array_merge($pagelist, $temp);   
fclose($file);                              
print_r($pagelist);                         
$lastten = array_slice($pagelist, -10, 10); 
print_r($lastten);
```

*I might be wrong about the slice offset and limit.

Comment: You need a loop for `fgetcsv` as it reads only a single line from the file.